# Поиск слова заданной длины с определенной буквой

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash

В процессе работы одного приложения плодятся логи с названиями вида:

```
013eStatus_1310
0Ewarning_19203
2011Status_0_reload
2011Warning_0
err_failure
017aStatus_1888
2016access_denied
014eStatus_1310
017eWarnings_000
```

Вопрос в том возможно ли одним регулярным выражением вытащить имена, чья длина 15-16 символов и при этом содержит букву `e`вне зависимости от регистра, иначе говоря в выводе должно оказаться нечто вроде:

```
013eStatus_1310
0Ewarning_19203
014eStatus_1310
017eWarnings_000
```

Answer (score 1):

Легче всего — в два `grep`:

```sh
$ grep -E -e '^.{15,16}$' ./file.txt | grep -F -e e -e E
```

Comment: >>`...grep -F -e e -e E` - могли бы объяснить почему именно такая конструкция, а не `grep -i  e` или `grep 'e\|E'` к примеру ?

Comment: Вполне.  `grep -F` часто быстрее на больших объёмах данных.  В этом примере это, скорее всего, неважно, но я уже воспитал в себе привычку использовать `grep -F`, когда регулярные выражения строго не требуются.

Comment: спасибо за пояснение, попробую протестировать по таймингу.

Comment: Судя по примеру вывода буква `e` имелась в виду только первая...

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
sed -r -n '/e|E/s/^(.{15,16})$/\1/pg' ./file.txt
```

Где 
`-r` - расширенные регулярные выражения
`-n` - тихий режим, для вывода указывается параметр `p`
`/e|E/` - шаблон для поиска строк
`^` - символ начала строки
`(` - начало группы захвата
`.` - выбор любого символа

---

*Если есть необходимость выбора только букв, цифр и символа нижнего подчеркивания, точку следует заменить на* `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

---

`{15,16}` - квантификатор, от 15 до 16 символов совпадение
`)` - конец группы  захвата
`$` - символ конца строки
`/\1/gp` - печать выбранной шаблоном группы